# Python Pandas - Formatting Into Excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get python pandas to properly format some data.

Right now it looks like this:

```
     Point     Time     Value
0    
1    
2    
3    
4    
5    
etc
```

I want it to look like this:

```
     Point1     Point2    Point3    etc...
Time1     
Time2    
Time3    
etc
```

So it will group all the data with the same timestamp into a row.
All the data with the same point will be in one column.

I am new to Panda - can someone please help me out? Any input appreciated.
When I tried doing a shift it said "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". How can I do this properly?

Comment: You need `df.pivot` or `pd.crosstab`. But how can we help you without your data? Please post some data we can work with.

Comment: No data, no help :-(